# how to detect the background color for a specific area?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I wrote a code that places a logo in an image based on the background color, if the background is dark it will place the light logo and if it is light it will place the dark logo. the problem is if the corner I placed the logo in is dark and the whole background is light it will place the dark logo so how can I fix this problem

here is the code:

> ```
> $filename = "logo_5.png";
>
> list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
> $ratio = $height/$width;
>
> $new_width = $frame_width;
> $new_height = $frame_width * $ratio;
>
> $temp_width = $frame_width/5;
> $temp_height = $temp_width * $ratio;
>
> $luminance = get_avg_luminance($target_file,10);
>             //echo "AVG LUMINANCE: $luminance<br />";
>
>             // assume a medium gray is the threshold, #acacac or RGB(172, 172, 172)
>             // this equates to a luminance of 170
>
>             if ($luminance > 170) {
>
>                 $socials_footer = "socials_7.png";
>             } else {
>               $socials_footer = "socials_8.png";
>
>             }
> ```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: There is also CSS's [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) that you may find useful as a lightweight alternative.

Comment: Keep in mind that any calculation of average luminance will not take into account hot/cold spots in the image. If you're doing this to ensure proper contrast for legibility/scannability of the logo on arbitrary backgrounds, then you might need something smarter.

Comment: You could try to crop the image to only leave the area where the logo will be placed. And then determine the average luminance of that, instead of the whole original image. If you do this in the browser, this would involve the canvas API a lot. In PHP I guess there are libraries to read from image files, crop etc..

Comment: Then of course there is the excellent [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick) library, that will provide you with functions like [getimagehistogram()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagehistogram.php).

Answer (score 0):

### I know this is not what you asked for but this is a CSS alternative:

you can accomplish switching color automatically based on the background color with a CSS **mix-blend-mode**, just make sure that the **background-color** of the **body** and **wrappers** are set before using this property on the logo

```
.logo{
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

- **Quick youtube Demo by Kevin Powell :** https://youtu.be/wLPIwZdo0gM
- **MDN docs :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode